# IIS and .NET 5 ASP.NET MVC 5 App, HttpsRedirect not working outside IIS Server

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core-mvc, iis-10, asp.net-core-5.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 5 MVC app, running fine on a IIS 10 server.

I've been asked to enable HTTPS and enforce it on port 6443. I have been given the certificate and configured it on IIS.

When going into Chrome locally on the server and going to `http://localhost`, you get correctly redirected to `https://localhost:6443`

Binding is configured:

[image]

Certificate is ok and locally it works.

When from another location in the network i visit the ip address of the server, if I visit it in https, it works.

If I visit in http, I get this chrome error:

> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED, check connection or proxy.

This does not make any sense, before enabling https, it was working fine on http:80, and locally, the redirection works.

This is how it's done in code (Startup.cs):

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
     if (appOptions.HttpsRedirectionEnabled)
     {
         app.UseHttpsRedirection();
     }

     // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change 
     // this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
     app.UseHsts();
}
```

and

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
                {
                    options.RedirectStatusCode = StatusCodes.Status301MovedPermanently;
                    options.HttpsPort = 6443;
                });
}
```

Also, visiting https://serverip seems to not work aswell, kinda like redirecting on 443 instead of 6443. So I get it working only locally.

I don't want to install any url rewrite stuff, this has to work normally.

What config I am missing on IIS or whatever else?

**EDIT**: been asked to add trace from chrome dev tools, here it is:

[image]

More detailed trace

[image]

Chrome hsts section:

[image]

But querying this finds stuff

[image]

Comment: Thanks to Microsoft's confusing version-naming strategy, ASP.NET MVC 5 is the version that runs on .NET Framework 4.8, *NOT* the version that runs on .NET 5.

Comment: Have you tried tracing the requests from another computer using the browser dev tools? You need to narrow down whether you're being redirected to the wrong port, or whether the port is blocked by the firewall.

Comment: @RichardDeeming adding them right now in question

Comment: From the trace, it looks like you're being redirected to port `443` instead of `6443`. But you've also got [HSTS headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Strict-Transport-Security) set, so Chrome has likely cached a redirection to the wrong port.

Comment: In Chrome, open `chrome://net-internals/#hsts` and search for your server name to see if it's in the list. If it is, you should be able to delete the cached entry from the same page.

Comment: HTTPS uses TLS for encrypting message.  TLS runs before the HTTPS request is sent.  The TLS server sends a certificate block with names of possible certificates.  Then client looks up the names of each certificate in stores to find matching certificate.  Possible reasons for failure 1) certificate is not in stores 2) Encryption mode of certificate isn't supported in client.  Since Net 4.7.2 TLS by default is run in operating system instead of Net.  Therefore the Operating System needs to support the TLS version and Encryption Mode.  What?

Comment: @RichardDeeming it's empty, look

Comment: @LiquidCore It won't show anything until you search for a site. You need to type in your server name and hit the "query" button.

Comment: @RichardDeeming done, sent you the result

Comment: @LiquidCore That shows you *do* have a cached HSTS entry for that server on port `443`. Try deleting it and accessing the `http:` version again, preferably with the browser's network trace running.

Comment: @RichardDeeming where it shows exactly? at which line?
But mostly important, how do I delete it?

Comment: @LiquidCore You may also need to disable HSTS for your application - as far as I can see, it only works for port `443`, as per [RFC 6797](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797).

Comment: @RichardDeeming Thank you very much I will try disable HSTS right now and see what happens!

Comment: @LiquidCore It found a match, and it says `FORCE_HTTPS`. You'll need to put your server name in the box further down the page under "Delete domain security policies".

Comment: @RichardDeeming a question, if hsts doesn't work, why on the server itself it works? It's something that is used only by the browser when connecting from outside?

Comment: @LiquidCore I suspect the HSTS header either isn't being sent, or isn't being honoured, for `localhost` access.

Comment: @RichardDeeming Looks like deleting those policies worked fine and now redirect works fine. Maybe under the hood it's discarding HSTS because port isn't 443, but THANK YOU VERY MUCH.

That said if you put it as an answer I will gladly give you the answer points

Comment: @RichardDeeming Can I also ask you how inbetween all of this you got a shot at this Chrome hidden settings? You had to deal with it before? How you know this obscure part of the http protocol?

Comment: @LiquidCore I've run into HSTS caching before, and a quick Google search found the right Chrome settings to use. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the browser had cached [an HSTS response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Strict-Transport-Security) for the server, telling it to always request the secure version of the site. As per [RFC 6797](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797), this will only ever redirect to port `443`.

Disabling the HSTS headers and clearing the cached response from Chrome (using the `chrome://net-internals/#hsts` settings page) resolved the issue.